# Как добиться подобного?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть проблемы: таблицами (или `div-ами`) добиться разделения колонок так, как на скрине. У границ `tr`, `td` могут ли быть отступы от краёв именно по границам? Или можно сверстать это 3-мя `div-ами`?

Comment: Дополню, таблица не фиксирована по длине.

Comment: Объясните подробнее, что вы хотите. Если вы имеете в виду отступы от границ таблицы, то для этого можете воспользоваться `css` свойством `padding` для элементов `td`.

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: Проблема в разделителях столбцов (день, дата, стоимость), точнее в том, что они не до конца края дива доходят, остаётся расстояние!

Comment: Можно использовать абсолютное позиционирование. Ну или не использовать таблицу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Таблицу вкладываем в любой блочный элемент с рамкой. Для каждой ячейки, начиная с второй устанавливаем только левую часть границы `border-left`. Не забываем про `border-collapse`, иначе разделитель не будет сплошной.

```
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
th:first-child,td:first-child{
  border-left: 0px; //убираем черту слева
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOLma)